# No results when implementing NLTK recursive descent parser

Tags: python, parsing, recursion, nlp, nltk

I am trying to implement a `NLTK` recursive descent parser using a grammar I constructed. When I run the code below, it does not print anything and the result is 'None'.

Why is this happening?

```py
from nltk import Nonterminal, nonterminals, Production, CFG
from nltk.parse import RecursiveDescentParser

nt1 = Nonterminal('NP')
nt2 = Nonterminal('VP')

S, NP, VP, PP = nonterminals('S, NP, VP, PP')
N, V, DT, JJ = nonterminals('N, V, DT, JJ')

prod1 = Production(S, [NP, VP])
prod2 = Production(NP, [DT, NP])

grammar = CFG.fromstring("""
S -> NP VP PP
NP -> DT JJ JJ N | N
VP -> VBD | V NP | V RB
PP -> P NP
N -> 'dog' 'Somebody''chair''back''coffee'
V -> 'stretched''slept''made'
P -> 'by' 'his' 'downstairs'
DT -> 'The' 'the' 'A'
JJ -> 'cheerful''black''sleepy''yellow'
RB -> 'quietly'
""")

rd = RecursiveDescentParser(grammar)

sentence1 = "The cheerful black dog slept quietly by the chair".split()
sentence2 = "A sleepy yellow dog stretched his back".split()
sentence3 = "Somebody downstairs made coffee".split()

for a in rd.parse(sentence1):
    print(a)
for a in rd.parse(sentence2):
    print(a)
for a in rd.parse(sentence3):
    print(a)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! See [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the guidance about *not posting screenshots of your code*: “DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question.”

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting any results because your grammar isn't correct/functional. I've posted a solution below that works with the sentences you have. Please note that the solution does not use a comprehensive grammar so you'll have to add more rules/cases to suit your needs. But first, I want to explain the gist of the Recursive Descent (RD) parser using a simple sentence. Hopefully it will help you understand how it works so that you can begin making your own grammar rules that work.

### Basic Recursive Parsing Example

The basic idea of the RD parser is to recursively apply some set of parsing rules. As a simple example, take the sentence "*the philosopher contemplated*" with the following basic rules:

```
S -> NP VP | N
NP -> DT N
VP -> V
DT -> 'the'
N -> 'philosopher'
V -> 'contemplated'
```

The parser will always start with the root `S` and begin expanding each of the rules in an attempt to find matches. For this example specifically, the RD parser carries out the following expansion and matching steps:

```
Start:
    [ * S ]
Expand: S -> NP VP
    [ * NP VP ]
Expand: NP -> DT N
    [ * DT N VP ]
Expand: DT -> 'the'
    [ * 'the' N VP ]
Match: 'the'
    [ 'the' * N VP ]
Expand: N -> 'philosopher'
    [ 'the' * 'philosopher' VP ]
Match: 'philosopher'
    [ 'the' 'philosopher' * VP ]
Expand: VP -> V
    [ 'the' 'philosopher' * V ]
Expand: V -> 'contemplated'
    [ 'the' 'philosopher' * 'contemplated' ]
Match: 'contemplated'
    [ 'the' 'philosopher' 'contemplated' ]
GOOD PARSE:
    [ 'the' 'philosopher' 'contemplated' ]
(S (NP (DT the) (N philosopher)) (VP (V contemplated)))
Expand: S -> N
    [ * N ]
Expand: N -> 'philosopher'
    [ * 'philosopher' ]
Backtrack: 'the' match failed
```

If you had more rules/cases, the parser would attempt to expand and match all of them to find suitable parses. With this basic example in mind, you should be able to reason why the following solution works.

### Solution

```py
from nltk import CFG
from nltk.parse import RecursiveDescentParser

grammar = CFG.fromstring("""
S -> NP VP | NP
NP -> DT N | DT JJ N | DT JJ JJ N | PRP N | N
VP -> V | NP V | V RB | V RB PP | V NP | RB V | RB V NP | V RB
PP -> P NP
DT -> 'the' | 'a'
N -> 'dog' | 'chair' | 'back' | 'somebody' | 'coffee'
PRP -> 'his'
V -> 'slept' | 'stretched' | 'made'
P -> 'in' | 'by'
JJ -> 'cheerful' | 'black' | 'sleepy' | 'yellow'
RB -> 'quietly' | 'downstairs'
""")


# Create function to recursively parse sentence using custom grammar rules
def get_rd_parse(my_grammar, my_sentence):
    rd = RecursiveDescentParser(my_grammar)  # Create RD parser
    # rd.trace(3)  # Debugging
    processed_sent = my_sentence.lower().split()  # Conv string to lower & split into tokens
    return rd.parse(processed_sent)  # Return parse


# Create sentences
sentences = [
    "The cheerful black dog slept quietly by the chair",
    "A sleepy yellow dog stretched his back",
    "Somebody downstairs made coffee"
]
# Parse sentences & display results
for i, sent in enumerate(sentences):
    print("-"*40 + "\nSentence #{}".format(i + 1))
    for node in get_rd_parse(grammar, sent):
        print(node)
```

### Output

```
----------------------------------------
Sentence #1
(S
  (NP (DT the) (JJ cheerful) (JJ black) (N dog))
  (VP (V slept) (RB quietly) (PP (P by) (NP (DT the) (N chair)))))
----------------------------------------
Sentence #2
(S
  (NP (DT a) (JJ sleepy) (JJ yellow) (N dog))
  (VP (V stretched) (NP (PRP his) (N back))))
----------------------------------------
Sentence #3
(S (NP (N somebody)) (VP (RB downstairs) (V made) (NP (N coffee))))
```